# php form is not updating database in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a table to display the top 10 high scores for a game by the users. i am trying to create a form which allows the user to enter their new high score in the form, hit submit, then the database is updated and the new leaderboard with the newly entered high score is displayed. but when i go to change the high score the database isnt updated and the table doesnt change. this is really frustraiting me and if anyone knows why this could be happening and could give some advice that would be great. my code is below/

```
<?php

class DatabaseManager
    {
        private $servername = "localhost";
        private $username = "root";
        private $password = "";
        private $dbname = "sokodatabase";
        private $dbc;

        function __construct() {
            $this->dbc = mysqli_connect($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);
        }

        function __destruct() {
            mysqli_close($this->dbc);
        }

        public function SelectHighScores(){
            // Create a query for the database
            $query = "
                    SELECT username, highScores, rankNo
                    FROM users, leaderboardhighscores
                    WHERE users.id = leaderboardhighscores.userId
                    ORDER BY highScores desc
                    LIMIT 10";

            // Get a response from the database by sending the connection
            // and the query
            $response = @mysqli_query($this->dbc, $query);

            // If the query executed properly proceed
            if($response){
                echo '<table>
                <tr><td><b>Rank</b></td>
                <td><b>Username</b></td>
                <td><b>High Score</b></td></tr>';


                // mysqli_fetch_array will return a row of data from the query
                // until no further data is available
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
                    echo '<tr><td>' .
                    $row['rankNo'] . '</td><td>' .
                    $row['username'] . '</td><td>' .
                    $row['highScores'] . '</td><td>';

                    echo '</tr>';
                }

                echo '</table>';
            } else {
                echo "Couldn't issue database query<br />";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

my html with php to create form...

```
                <div class = "leaderboard">
                        <?php

    // Get a connection for the database

    require_once('../sokodatabase.php');
    $manager = new DatabaseManager;
    $manager->SelectHighScores(); 

    //if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

          //require_once('../sokodatabase.php');  
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
                    $query = "
                    UPDATE leaderboardHighScores
                    SET highScores=".$_POST["highScores"].", rankNo=".$_POST["rankNo"]."
                    WHERE userId=".$_POST["userId"];

                //var_dump($_POST); 
                //echo $query;

                @mysqli_query($this, $query);
            }
    //}       


    ?>

    <form method="post" action="highScores.php">
        high score <input type="text" name="highScores"/>
        rankNo <input type="text" name="rankNo"/>
        userId <input type="text" name="userId"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: What datatypes are highScore, rankNo and userId

Comment: they are int (not string)

Comment: You are doing no error checking and yo have used the `@` in front of `mysqli_query` try checking for an error after issueing that update

Comment: Also is `$this` the correct connection handle name to use here in `@mysqli_query($this, $query);`

Comment: As your silence makes me assume this was just a `$this` typo I shall flag this for closure for that reason. As it stands the question will probably not be of any use to others. Please comment if I am wrong and I will remove my close action.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, it might still be of help to beginners as this is a basic situation; I've further broken this down in my answer below and may help others as a pointer

Comment: @x3ns Thats a nice answer, so I will leave it up to 4 other people to agree with me and if there are not 4 others that agree the question will stay open. It just bugs me when the questioner just disappears when someone spots a simple typo rather than saying Woops silly me, or something to indicate a solution has been found, as currently we just have to assume that and thats no help at all to others

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks. I understand; but at the end of the day, just hope it helps others as well, even if their the silent kind :)

Comment: it wasnt a $this that is the proplem, I change it to $dbc and nothing happens,then i change it to $this->dbc and still nothing happens. i really cant understand why this isnt working for me

Comment: @Phill, You wouldn't be able to access `dbc` outside the class since it's a private variable. You can't use `$this` outside the class. If you REALLY want to do this without using my answer below, you'll have to make `dbc` public and then use `$manager->dbc`.

Comment: What I find really frustrating is when coders stick error suppression labels ('@' in this instance) in front of their code and then tell us they don't know what the error is.

Comment: So in fact it was a `$this` problem.

Answer (score 2):

First off, for security measures, **always** sanitize user input before using in a query.

Second, you also don't need the `@` before `mysqli_query` - unless your trying to suppress any and all erorrs/warnings thrown by the function.

Third, try and use the same cases for your SQL; you used `leaderboardhighscores` in the class, and then `leaderboardHighScores` in the second part of your code; I don't know which one's the real name in the database but will assume for former is since that is working as you say. I'm saying this because case-sensitivity could result an issue, please read [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) on this matter.

Fourth, you are using `$this` outside of a class on a page where it has no meaning (if not another).

Add this function to the `DatabaseManager` class:

```
public function SetHighScores($uid, $score, $rank) {
    $uid   = mysql_real_escape_string($uid);
    $score = mysql_real_escape_string($score);
    $rank  = mysql_real_escape_string($rank);

    $query = "UPDATE leaderboardhighscores SET highScores='{$score}', rankNo='{$rank}' WHERE userId='{$uid}';";

    return mysqli_query($this->dbc, $query);
}
```

And then this would go on your page:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $manager->SetHighScores($_POST['userId'], $_POST['highScores'], $_POST['rankNo']);
}
```

Also, you should look into [PDO_MYSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), would be a better option to go for, but I understand what you're doing is good for learning the basics I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try this then

```
$result = mysqli_query($manager->dbc, $query);
if ( ! $result ) {
    echo 'Error code ' 
         . mysqli_errno($manager->dbc)
         . ' Error message ' 
         . mysqli_error($manager->dbc);
}
```

As $manager is the variable that is holding your DatabaseManager class's object instance within the scope of the code that is executing, and that object has a property called `dbc` that contains the database connection handle.

As @x3ns says in his/her comment you will also need to change the DatabaseManager code like this

```
class DatabaseManager
    {
        private $servername = "localhost";
        private $username = "root";
        private $password = "";
        private $dbname = "sokodatabase";

        public  $dbc;    //<-- change here
```

So that you can access that property from outside the object itself.

This is a quick fix but to be honest you would be better stopping and reading @x3ns's answer and applying most if not all of his/her suggestion.

Although I would like to add one more.

It is very bad practice to generate output directly from a class method as you have in `public function SelectHighScores()`

Directly echoing from a method totally destroys the ability to subclass and amend the activity of that method. It is far better to generate the output into a variable and return that variable. Then if I want to subclass your method I have the option of amending its result in some way if I need to.

Comment: `dbc` is a private variable within the class, it has to first be set as public to be accessed as `$manager->dbc`

Comment: Yea thats a very good point I missed that. Looks like he needs to do some major refactoring of this code

Answer (score -1):

Try replace:

```
@mysqli_query($this, $query);
```

With:

```
@mysqli_query($this->dbc, $query);
```

Comment: Good idea, wish I had thought about that 2 minutes ago. By the way, have you got any idea what $this is set to in the code the OP has shown us, or are you clarevoyant.